# My cat's breathing sounds like it has reduced flow

Tags: cats, health

We adopted a stray kitty 3 months ago, it is pretty young and I wouldn't give it more than 5 months of age. We cleaned it from parasites but haven't really taken it to the vet yet (I know I know). Other than the parasites, it looks and behaves healthy, eats good, has those high levels of energy cats have and is a real speed demon. We bathe him regularly and cleaned him off fleas also.

We recently allowed him to sleep in our room, sometimes with us in the bed. That is when I noticed he makes a slight noise when breathing trough his nose. It doesn't sound labored or heavy or anything like that but like there is something in the way of the air.

Is this something we should be worried about ?

Comment: Doesn't sound like something I'd worry about.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds perfectly normal, especially while sleeping. In case you forgot, humans' breathing is also much louder while sleeping. The muscles in your mouth and throat relax, which makes them vibrate in the air flow. The same happens for cats.

I've heard cats snore, chirp or even make a high-pitched whistling sound (although very quiet) while asleep and the second they awake, it's gone. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: He does it when he is awake also, when he finally gets to sit still for a minute you can actually hear it. But it doesn't seem to affect him in any way, like I said he is a speed demon